# async and await on MySQL call in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

all I'm pretty new to node and I just learned about the async and await function offered in javascript. I'm trying to implement this method in the code snippet attached below. From my understanding, the database response should first print out to the console and then the "done", but I can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please also try to explain what you did to fix it, because I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
const cTable = require('console.table');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8889,
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "testDB"
})

connection.connect((err, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err.code);
    }
});

var displayDB = async () => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM products', (err, resp) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err.code);
        } else {
            table = [];
            resp.forEach((product) => {
                obj = {
                    'Product ID': product.productID,
                    'Category': product.category,
                    'Price': product.price,
                    'Stock': product.stockQuantity
                }
                table.push(obj)
            })
            console.table(table)
            connection.end()
        }
    })
}

var test = async () => {
    var x = await displayDB()
    console.log('done')
}
test()
```

Comment: This isn't going to work unless `connection.query` returns a promise. I haven't looked in a while, but I don't think the MySQL node module does. So you would need to wrap that in a promise and return the promise from the function.

Comment: @MarkMeyer — It wouldn't work even if `connection.query` did return a promise, since the return value of `connection.query` is ignored inside `displayDB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `return` statement in your `displayDB` function.

Normally this would cause a function to return `undefined`, but because you declared it `async`, it causes it to return a Promise that is **immediately** resolved.

If you want it to wait until the database query is complete, then you need to **explicitly** return a `new Promise` which *you* `resolve` when you are ready (i.e. after you have called `connection.end()`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to return a promise from the async function `displayDB` if you want to use the `await` keyword in test, you need to learn how promises work first. Pseudo code :

```
var displayDB = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM products', (err, resp) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                const table = [];
                resp.forEach((product) => {
                    obj = {
                    'Product ID': product.productID,
                    'Category': product.category,
                    'Price': product.price,
                    'Stock': product.stockQuantity
                    }
                    table.push(obj)
                })
                resolve(table)
            }
        })
    })
}


var test = async () => {
   try{
    console.table(await displayDB())
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
    connection.end()
}
test()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: `You need to return a promise from an async function` not really. The `async function` is not doing anything here, it could be a regular function. You don't have to return a promise from an async function as it does so itself.

Comment: to exploit the await keyword you need to resolve a promise in this example. It's all about context. The promise returns a result here, table.